# Como funciona este metodo ActionListener?

Tags: java, funciones, eclipse, eventos

Soy algo nuevo en esto y quería saber como trabaja este pedazo de código, por que razón se abren unas llaves dentro del método, cuenta como otro parámetro?. Y que tan eficiente es crear eventos de esta manera para botones(?

```
 boton2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    try {
                        label1.setText(boton2.getText());
                            
                    } catch (Exception ew) {
                   

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Al agregar el evento de esa manera lo que haces es instanciar una clase anonima que implementa la interfaz ActionListener, cuando implementas una interfaz debes sobreescribir todos sus metodos, en este caso actionPerformed. Cuando el boton detecta un evento y tiene un ActionListener, el boton va a llamar al metodo ActionPerformed del listener y en este caso poner texto en tu label

Comment: Oh ya veo, si mas o menos ya entendí debo entender mas lo de las interfaces supongo, muchas gracias uwu